# Lines passing through many points of the form $(c^n,c^m)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, plane-geometry

For $c>1$ consider the subset $X\subset \mathbb R^2$ consisting of all points $(c^n,c^m)$ where $n,m\in \mathbb Z$.

**Question.** Suppose $L\subset \mathbb R^2$ is a line that is not horizontal, not vertical and doesn't pass through $(0,0)$. What is the maximal number of points from $X$ that $L$ can contain? (you can vary $c$)

**PS.** It would be great even to prove that such a number is bounded (if this is so). So far best examples have $4$ points on one line (the first one by David Speyer in the comments).

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe such a maximal number exists and the value can't instead be unbounded?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I don't have an argument that shows that this number is bounded, so if you can prove that it's unbounded, that would be great. But if you can give at least one  $c$ and one $L$ where this number is at least $5$ (say), that would be interesting as well

Comment: Do I infer from your response that you have examples with 4 collinear points? What is an example?

Comment: David, sorry, I don't have an example with 4 points :). I just took 5 to be safer, so yes, an example with 4 points will be interesting as well...

Comment: Okay, I have an example with 4. Let $c$ be the real root of $x^3-x-1$. Then $(c^4,c^0)$, $(c^3,c^2)$, $(c^2,c^3)$ and $(c^0,c^4)$ are colinear. Experiments suggest that, if $0 < p,q < n < p+q$ then there is a $c>1$ which makes $(c^n,c^0)$, $(c^q, c^p)$, $(c^p, c^q)$ and $(c^0, c^n)$ collinear.

Comment: An equivalent problem is to determine (one plus) the maximum possible multiplicity of the multi-set $\{ \frac{c^n-1}{c^m-1}: n,m \in {\bf Z} \backslash \{0\}; n \neq m \}$ for a real number $c>1$.

Comment: A similar example to that given by @DavidESpeyer is to take as $c$ the real root of $x^3 + x + 1$. Then $c^0 + c^1 = c^2 + c^5 = c^4 + c^6 (= -c^3)$, giving a set of six points.

Comment: I can't find any sets of more than 6 points with exponents below 60 using this technique (lines of the form $x + y = k$).

Comment: Peter, thanks for the example. I asked in the problem for examples with $c>1$, but you example is interesting

Comment: Oops. I'll add a real root range filter and rerun the search.

Comment: Ok, all of the examples with exponents up to 60 have a single root, which is always negative.

Comment: I did some experimentation and looked at the polynomial $f_{n,p,q}(c)$ which vanishes when $(c^n,c^0)$, $(c^p, c^q)$, $(c^q, c^p)$, $(c^0, c^n)$ are collinear. This polynomial is easily seen to be divisible by $c^{GCD(n,p,q)}-1$. Once this factor is stripped off, the other factor appears to always be irreducible (checked for $1 \leq p,q,n \leq 20$). If this is true, it is easy to see that the $f_{n,p,q}$'s must all have distinct roots from each other.

Comment: Generalising my previous search code to lines of the form $x + \alpha y = k$ and leaving $\alpha$ as a variable, the search is much slower but finds almost 2700 four-point lines with exponents between 0 to 19 (and none with more than four points). That's sufficiently sparse in the search space that picking random exponents and looking for lines (Monte Carlo searching) isn't likely to work. [Code and results](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/3fff29469fd0b61b5a53282c5657f5e9). Running time was approx 45 hours.

Comment: Maybe it's worth writing down that for any $c$ the number is (effectively) bounded by $S$-unit equation arguments, but if you just ask about $c$-units instead of powers of $c$ uniformity becomes false, so this is really about powers and is impervious to Diophantine methods around Siegel's theorem... Or maybe you could run the $S$-unit argument with extra info on the exponents and see if something comes out?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Mathematica code to look for solutions to this, and I find that all the solutions with exponents up to $\pm30$ have only four points.

I looked for solutions in the form $$\{\{a,b\},\,p(x)\}$$ representing the line through $(1,1)$ whose next point is at $(x^a,x^b)$, where $p$ is irreducible, $a>0$, and $x>1$ is a root of $p$.

For instance, the line
through the points
$$\{\{x^0,x^0\},\{x^3,x^8\},\{x^4,x^{10}\},\{x^9,x^{18}\}\}$$
has the solution
$$\{\{3,8\},1+x^2+x^4-x^5-x^7\}.$$

All the solutions so far have polynomials with only $\pm1$ coefficients, usually with all the positives before the negatives. So from here someone may want to search for other solutions with similar coefficient patterns.

Meanwhile here is the code I used, with commentary.

We represent the pair of points $(x^a,x^b)$ and $(x^c,x^d)$ by the quadruple $a,b,c,d$, and loop over quadruples with $-n<a,b,c,d<n$.

```
Simplify[Det[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, x^a, x^b}, {1, x^c, x^d}}]]
poly[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := (-x^a + x^b + x^c - x^(b+c) - x^d + x^(a+d)) / x^Min[a, b, c, d]
bigfactor[p_] := Select[First /@ FactorList[p], (# /. x->1) (# /. x->2) < 0 &]
normalize[p_] := p/Sign[p /. x->0]
solution[v_] := {v[[1 ;; 2]], v // poly // bigfactor // First // normalize}
solution[{3, 8, 4, 10}]
```

For any $a,b,c,d$, there is a polynomial which vanishes when $(x^0,x^0)$, $(x^a,x^b)$ and $(x^c,x^d)$ are collinear. It has the especially simple form $-x^a + x^b + x^c - x^{b+c} - x^d + x^{a+d}$ if $a,b,c,d$ are all positive, and can be shifted from that by $x^{\min(a,b,c,d)}$ if one of the variables is negative. We want an $x>1$ which is a root of this polynomial.

In other words, we want a factor of this polynomial with a root greater than 1. So we look for an irreducible factor which has different signs at 1 and at 2; since this factor always seems to be unique, we take only the first such factor. As an example, this procedure gets us from the quadruple $(3,8,4,10)$ to the solution above.

```
poly[{a, b, c, d}] /. x->2 // Simplify
poly02[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := -2^a + 2^b + 2^c - 2^(b+c) - 2^d + 2^(a+d)
D[poly[{a, b, c, d}], {x, 2}] /. x->1 // Simplify
poly21[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := a d - b c
goodquad[v_] := (v[[3]] > v[[1]] > 0) && (poly02[v] poly21[v] < 0)
quadruples[n_] := Select[Tuples[Range[n, -n], 4], goodquad]
quadruples[7]
```

We only need to consider quadruples $a,b,c,d$ which yield polynomials with roots bigger than $1$. Given the form of the polynomial, it will always have a double root at $1$, and always have the same sign at $2$ as it does for all higher values. So it is enough to look at quadruples for which *poly''(1) poly(2) < 0*. We also restrict to $c>a>0$.

```
bestof[n_] := bestof[n] = Commonest[solution /@ quadruples[n]]
check[b_, v_] := PolynomialMod[poly[Join[b[[1]], v]], b[[2]]]
exponents[b_, n_] := Select[Tuples[Range[-n, n], 2], check[b, #] == 0 &]
exponents[n_] := exponents[bestof[n] // Last, n]
bestof[19]
exponents[19]
```

We find the solution for all quadruples under consideration (and this is the computationally expensive step). E.g., the solution above occurs for the two quadruples $(3,8,4,10)$ and $(3,8,9,18)$. We take the solutions which appear most often, hoping to find one which appears three times even though all of the current examples appear only once or twice.

In order to make the solutions easy to count, we excluded the $c$'s and $d$'s from them. So after finding a commonly occurring solution, we can (cheaply) loop through all the possible $c$'s and $d$'s to see which points are on the associated line.

This approach is $O(n^4)$, since it involves looping through quadruples. It takes about a minute for the case $n=19$. Fortunately it never uses explicit algebraic numbers or real approximations; it sticks to integers and polynomials with integer coefficients, which lets it loop through the possibilities quickly.

Comment: Got it: scale the gradient by $x^u$. Curiously, though, despite including negative exponents in the search range I'm not seeing any in the solutions. Do you have the same observation, or do I have a bug? I also find that thinking about the scaling this way has made me look again at the differences between the exponents in each pair: since the differences must be distinct, perhaps a search strategy would be to look at sets of exponents with pairwise distinct differences rather than small exponents.

Comment: I see plenty of negative exponents in solutions like this.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure that I get it, when you say "and always have the same sign at 2 as it does for all higher values" this is also a reflection of the fact that for $c>2$ a line can not contain $3$ points in this problem? This is because in your poly the largest of 6 terms dominates the  smaller ones for $x\ge 2$.

Comment: @aglearner, that is correct.